# Determine a and b in Van Der Waals equation with series of (x,y) from excel

Tags: python, scipy

I need to determine the values from a and b in Van Der Waals equation using a non linear adjustment. I don’t know almost nothing about sci-py. I found out that scipy.optimize.curve_fit does a non linear adjustment by least squares, but I am not sure if I am using it right. I already searched out but found nothing to change it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

r = 8.314472
t = 273

data = pd.read_excel("gases_data.xls", skiprows=2)

pressure = np.array(data.get(data.columns[0]))
hydrogen = np.array(data.get(data.columns[1]))
nitrogen = np.array(data.get(data.columns[3]))

def ff(L, a, b):
    return (r*t)/(L - b) - (a/L**2)

pfit, perr = curve_fit(ff,hydrogen,pressure)
y_fit = ff(hydrogen, *pfit)

plt.plot(hydrogen, pressure, "ro", label = "data")
plt.plot(hydrogen, y_fit, "b", label = "fit")

plt.text(10, 3, "a = " + str(pfit[0]) + "\nb = " + str(pfit[1]))

plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLWfP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvBAI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

van der Waals is not the best function for straight `curve_fit`. Try increasing the arguments you pass to the function (e.g. creating the jacobian and adding boundaries)

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants as spc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R = spc.R
T = spc.convert_temperature(0, 'C', 'K')


l_data = np.linspace(0.1, 20, 30)
a, b = 2.45e-2 , 26.61e-6

def P_vdw(L, a, b):
    return R * T / (L - b) - a / L**2

def jac(L, a, b):
    return np.array([-1 / L**2, R * T / (L - b)**2]).T

p_data = P_vdw(l_data, a * np.random.normal(1, 0.001, 30), b* np.random.normal(1, 0.001, 30))

plt.semilogy(l_data, p_data)
popt, popv = curve_fit(P_vdw, l_data, p_data, jac=jac,
                       bounds=[(1e-3, 1e-7), (1.0, 1e-6)],
                       method='trf')
plt.semilogy(l_data, P_vdw(l_data, *popt), 'ro')
print(popt)
```